# Open multiple .bat files with NotePad++ using a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, notepad++

Currently I use .bat files such as the following to open multiple .yml files across different location:

```
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 1\settings.yml"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 2\settings.yml"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 3\settings.yml"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 4\settings.yml"
```

This works correctly for .txt, .yml, .json, files and more.
However if I attempt to use the same procedure for opening .bat files, it fails.

Example:

```
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 1\start1.bat"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 2\start2.bat"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 3\start3.bat"
START "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 4\start4.bat"
```

My goal is to open these .bat files in notepad++ for editing.
Instead, windows actually attempts to open the start*.bat files themselve outside of notepad++

Comment: Do you need the `start` command at all?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, my assumption/interpretation is that each is to be run in parallel, _(each opened before the previous has been closed)_, as opposed to in series, _(one after the other)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example syntax is incorrect.

Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to see its usage information.

```
START ["title"] [command/program] [parameters]
```

Your working syntax, is only working by luck, because it is seeing `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` as the title, and then opening a registered filetype `.yml` using its default program. Luckily your default program for those files is Notepad++, and that is the only reason it is working as intended.

The syntax you should be using is:

```
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 1\settings.yml"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 2\settings.yml"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 3\settings.yml"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 4\settings.yml"
```

…and

```
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 1\start1.bat"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 2\start2.bat"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 3\start3.bat"
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\Location 4\start4.bat"
```

The first set of (empty) double-quotes is the window title, (the title doesn't need to be empty), and is required because the start command treats the first double-quoted argument as a title.